# How to run a linux command imediatly after exit chroot

Tags: linux

I am in change root, then I type exit command.

How to make a command run autimatically(in real environment, not change root)after that command excute.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply wrap your chroot command.

```
$chroot() {
> /bin/chroot "$@"
> echo goodby
> }
$ chroot /
exit
goodby
```